# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable while using nginx/traefik with EasyPanel & BTCPayServer?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps, reverse-proxy

I'm doing this all on Debian 12 VPS.

- I can install [easypanel](https://easypanel.io) separately & get it working with SSL enabled.
- I can install [btcpayserver](https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-docker/) separately using [this guide](https://sethforprivacy.com/guides/accepting-monero-via-btcpay-server/) to get BTC/XMR working.
- But I can't manage to get both of them working on the same VPS at the same time.

I'v tried installing Easypanel first & then installing BTCPayServer but BTCPayServer doesn't get installed at all giving me an error that says:

```
ERROR: for nginx: Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated
```

Now I've went the opposite way & installed BTCPayServer first & later on installed EasyPanel.

Now it is working.

But I can't access my `Next.js` app that is running on `easypanel`. I can't even setup a custom URL that on `easypanel.mysite.com` for some reason.

I'm thinking this is due to Nginx which BTCPayServer uses or Traefik which EasyPanel uses.

I currently get `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` when I try to open the Next.js app I installed on EasyPanel.

How do I go about solving this problem?

Easypanel has a [doc about this](https://easypanel.io/docs/guides/custom-traefik-config). So I did what it said with the help of [Perplexity](https://perplexity.ai):

#### /etc/easypanel/traefik/config/custom.yaml

```yaml
# Enable debug logs
log:
  level: DEBUG

# Define the entry points
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

# Enable and configure Let's Encrypt
certificatesResolvers:
  myresolver:
    acme:
      email: "myemail@gmail.com"
      storage: "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: "web"

# Configure the API
api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true

# Define the global configuration
global:
  checkNewVersion: true
  sendAnonymousUsage: true

# Configure access to Docker
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

# Configure the entry points for the services
http:
  routers:
    btcpayserver-router:
      rule: "Host(`btcpay.mysite.com`)"
      service: "btcpayserver-service"
      entryPoints:
        - "websecure"
    easypanel-router:
      rule: "Host(`easypanel.mysite.com`)"
      service: "easypanel-service"
      entryPoints:
        - "websecure"

  services:
    btcpayserver-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://btcpayserver-docker:80"
    easypanel-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://easypanel:80"
```

But I can't find out what `http://btcpayserver-docker:80` should be replaced with.

When I ran `docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}"` I got this:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAMES
969e4c50ec21   easypanel.1.vzayltvbta10oaqc3wpnztkq2
37e61e15eab5   sinister-kings_nextjs-app.1.lym2ck5oa18gdtfr3lcirz9rf
7999d7177605   letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
24691446a0bd   nginx-gen
d295cc6dbcd3   btcpayserver_monero_wallet
9f2ed203c36d   generated_nbxplorer_1
b9b8b4463c3d   btcpayserver_bitcoind
f6337df09401   generated_btcpayserver_1
696ff12c318d   tor-gen
aa89e0b619b2   generated_postgres_1
fe8d006707dd   nginx
11cf23a5363d   btcpayserver_monerod
f7d42ade4300   tor
```

Which one of the `btcpayserver` do I use on the custom traefik config? Is that config all I need?

I know I have to use Reverse Proxy & make one of them go through the others ports but I'm confused on how do I make that work?

Comment: On serverfault there is a canned closed response regarding using control panels - as long as you do very simple things they make your life easier. But when you start trying to solve non-trivial problems they get in the way. You are not just using a control panel - you are using 2 different ones to control the same service. This is not going to end well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not possible to answer without a LOT of investigation of the target system

Comment: @symcbean the control panel works fine. it makes a whole lot of deployments easy & 1-click. btcpayserver works fine too. the problem is getting them to work on the same server with my limited devops knowledge. i know its just setting some traefik commands but idk which. besides what's the point of closing a question that is even a little bit complex? i promise it doesn't take a lot of time. maybe 5 mins tops. for easypanel, its 2 commands. for btcpayserver, 3 commands that you can see in the sethforprivacy guide to see the error. should be easy (maybe 10-15 mins?) for an expert.

Comment: I don't have access to your machine to see how it is actually configured. I don't have the time to walk you through the process of finding this information yourself.

Comment: @symcbean no one is forcing you to. why close a genuine question? i'm sure someone might face a similar issue if they use a control panel with btcpayserver. i faced it twice with different control panels so i'm learning traefik but still would love pointers from someone more experienced. besides, i have no configurations. just installed debian 12 on a vps & installed easypanel & btcpayserver following sethforprivacy tutorial linked above. required config is mentioned in sethforprivacy guide.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at the instructions you posted, `btcpayserver` makes some assumptions that it is the only web service running, and defaults to using ports (i.e. 80, 443, 8080) that will conflict with EasyPanel which also makes assumptions it is the only web service running on a server.  Due to these assumptions, you are unable to use the defaults for both services and would require additional configuration not included in the "getting started" documentation to work together.

My first suggestion would be to install `btcpayserver` using EasyPanel as it is just a collection of Docker images, but the way `btcpayserver` was designed may not make that easy.  Maybe submit a request to the developer of `btcpayserver` to see if they would add an EasyPanel install option or you could develop it yourself and contribute to the project.

Another option I can think of would be to adjust all of the configured ports of either EasyPanel or `btcpayserver` to not be in conflict with each other.  Should be doable with some basic Docker networking knowledge.  Without experience with both services, I cannot comment how difficult this task may be.

The final option that comes to mind, and possibly the easiest, would be to just run the two services on two separate servers.  You could also use virtualization to achieve the same results.

Comment: i have found multiple options:

1. submit templates to easypanel but like you said it requires huge configuration because btcpayserver doesn't have docker-compose.yml but generates it via dotnet which is very weird
2. use easypanel custom traefik. i've learnt the basics of traefik & should be able to pass ports 80, 443, 8080 someway. this looks easiest.
3. what you said. i'll run btcpayserver with btc/xmr on a buffy $15/mo vps. $5/mo vps should be enough for easypanel.

anyways, thanks for taking a look. gonna learn myself some devops. bdw how did you get the port 8080 is being used?

Comment: I had noticed that the `btcpayserver` implementation of `traefik` was using port 8080:  https://github.com/btcpayserver/btcpayserver-docker/blob/master/docker-compose-generator/docker-fragments/traefik.yml